# О "белом гетто"

Tags: орфография, лексика, значение-слов, история

Что такое "белое гетто"? Почему оно *белое*? Как верно с точки зрения орфографии пишется это словосочетание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ghetto – (определение) (имя существительное)
a part of a city, especially a slum area, occupied by a minority group or groups.

Часть города, особенно трущобы (бедные районы), заселённые преимущественно общественными меньшинствами или группами меньшинств.

Исходя из определения, "белое гетто" — это часть года, где живут небогатые белые люди белой расы, в численности, — которая по отношению к общей численности города и с учётом его этнического состава, — является меньшинством.

Слово гетто может так же использоваться для обозначения бедных районов, при условии, что люди проживающие там являются значительно беднее остального населения города и в процентном соотношении являются меньшинством.

В просторечии слово "гетто" может употребляться для оскорбления жителей какого-то района, даже если он таковым не является. А добавление к слову прилагательного этнического окраса используется для эмоционального усиления.

Дополнительная информация:
гетто: 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE

трущобы: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B